# Google Sheets formula if formula help, leave blank if criteria isn't achieved for patient graduation date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am a common user, not a developer. I've added a copy of the google sheets spreadsheet below if you'd like to look at it.

This is a patient graduation list for physical therapy visits. I would like to determine if someone has graduated on time, then use that to calculate graduation on time percentage and graduation percentage total for a given month.

I would like to be able to input the date they graduated and have it return yes or no, but leave it blank if there is no date that is populated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IuYBBA8CgBvsUn1azWyP6y4HH9fxNiI4Qp6JL8P4Gi8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en) to check if there is a date in the `D` column, and use your previous formula if that's not the case:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),,IF(D2<=C2,"Yes","No"))
```